# re.search in python running slow, seeking alternative

Tags: python

i have the following code:

```
#CODEA
with open(logfile) as input_data:
    mylist = []
    rangelines = 0
    BeginSearchDVar = CTFBegin
    EndinSearchDVar = CTFEndin
    for line in input_data:
        if str(BeginSearchDVar) in str(line[0:30]):
            ......
```

Which use to be:

```
#CODEB
with open(logfile) as input_data:
    mylist = []
    rangelines = 0
    BeginSearchDVar = CTFBegin
    EndinSearchDVar = CTFEndin
    for line in input_data:
        if re.search(BeginSearchDVar) in line[0:30]:
            ......
```

**CODEB** worked well for my purposes but was quite slow.  So, I used **CODEA**.

The problem is, **CODEA** does not appear to do well with simple regexes.

For instance, suppose the content of line[0:30] was:

"Who are you? Hello, my name is Bond. James Bond.".

If the search pattern in the BeginSearchDVar variable contained the string "Who are.*Bond.*James.*Bond", CODEA would not find it.  CODEA does not like the ".*".

How can I efficiently address this?  I can't and don't want to use CODEB because it is far too slow when compared to CODEA.

Comment: You want to use regex without using regex?

Comment: no. as you might be aware of, there are more than one ways to do different things.  what i showed in my post are the only methods that I'm aware of.  but i know enough to know there may be other ways to address my main concerns.  so if you know of a different route, please provide detailed response on it. thank you.

Comment: I assume you compiled the regex? What is the value of `CTFBegin`? You could try stripping punctuation but I'm not sure if that's any quicker. How many lines of data are we talking about?

Comment: im not sure I know how to compile a regex properly. i simply assigned a string pattern to the CTFBegin variable.  and searched for that string in the line being read.

Comment: Your `CODEA` example doesn't contain regex searches. You are checking for a literal string there.